# Nested method calls in objective c

Tags: objective-c

Hey i have just started out with objective-c and i came across the nested messaging concept.I don't understand why we have to use and how it's used syntactically and semantically.

For example:

```
[[myAppObject theArray] insertObject:[myAppObject objectToInsert] atIndex:0]
```

This was one i came across.My problem is that i don't know what **[myAppObject theArray]** is doing.Is it creating an instance of **myAppObject** or is there a class by that name with the method **theArray**?

Can anyone shed light light on this topic?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: This is a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it creating an instance of myAppObject or is there a class by that
>   name with the method theArray

Neither; `myAppObject` is an instance of class `MyAppObject` (assuming conventional naming has been used) and the instance method, or property, `theArray` is being sent a message on that instance.

So `MyAppObject` would look something like this:

```
@interface MyAppObject : NSObject {
    NSArray *_theArray;   // This is optional, and considered to be old fashioned
                          // (but not by me).
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *theArray;

...

@end
```

Which has been allocated like this, somewhere:

```
MyAppObject *myAppObject = [[MyAppObject alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 4):

That is an example of nested method calls.  Simply:

`[myAppObject theArray]` is returning an array.

`[myAppObject objectToInsert]` is returning an object.

So:

`[[myAppObject theArray] insertObject:[myAppObject objectToInsert] atIndex:0]`

is the same as:

`[an_array insertObject:an_object atIndex:0]`

Answer (score 2):

`[myAppObject theArray]` -- `myAppObject` is a variable that contains an object of a class that has a method `myArray`, which is (hopefully) returning an array.

If you're used to other OOP languages, think of that line this way:

```
myAppObject.theArray.insertObjectAtIndex(myAppObject.objectToInsert, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the same as doing:

```
NSArray *myarray = [myAppObject theArray];

id object = [myAppObject objectToInsert];

myArray insertObject:object atIndex:0]
```

The first line returns the object `theArray` that is stored on the class `myAppObject`, that is an instance on `MyAppObject`.

Answer (score 1):

- If *myAppObject* is a class, then **theArray** is a *class* method of
  myAppObject.
- If *myAppObject* is an instance of a class, then
  **theArray** is an *instance* method of that class.

It's the same doing `obj.method()` in Java or `$obj->method()` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is short version. Other wise you have to do things like this;
`NSArray *array = [myAppObject theArray];`// object returning the arry named theArray.

After that its calling insert Object method on that array.
`[array insertObject:[myApObject objectTOInsert] atIndex:0]`;// inserting object at index 0. `[myAppobject objectToInsert]` returining object same like we got array.